# Fall back to FileStore on RedisStore becoming unavailable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, redis

I'm using Redis (using the redis-store) as the cache store for my Rails 4 app. However, if I kill my redis-server, the app errors out (Redis not found error). Whats the best way to either revert to the FileStore or not cache at all when the cache store becomes unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Rails support this out of the box. You might try the [`activesupport-cascadestore` gem](https://github.com/jch/activesupport-cascadestore). It seems a bit older now, but at least you might get some inspiration from it.

Alternatively, you might look into a process monitoring solution, such as [god](http://godrb.com/), to ensure your Redis gets restarted automatically if it gets killed.